# Develop WPF App like Windows 10 Setting App

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, windows-10

This question is just about how to develop an `WPF` app with control styles exactly matching with Windows 10 Settings APP.
In windows 10 setting App have different styles for `combobox`, `toggle button` `slider control` etc.

[image: windows 10 setting app]

Are these custom style available right away to use from Microsoft(`.NET` platform)? Or I need to work my ass off to match these windows controls.

Or any other third party extension or tool available for the same.

All the suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: I think you are after a [Universal Windows Platform](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/design/design-basics) app, **not** a WPF desktop app.

Comment: @MikeEason Are these controls readily available on UWP app platform directly?

Comment: I got the answer for this. In UWP all these controls are readily available.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this as well. UWP is **NOT** the answer if your needs fall out of normie app usage. They keep closing down functionality in the new platforms, .NET Core for example doesn't have codepage 437 support (absolutely necessary for ANSI control characters in a console), UWP is very bad on the image side about accessing pixels directly, it requires a lot of fiddling to get the bytes from an Image directly, StorageFile limits access to files, the platform is very limited for good old basic Win32 stuff, but I want modern UI style (WPF is ugly IMO).

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way would be to create your apps as Windows 10 UWP apps of course.

But if you want to stick with WPF, there are several libraries already available (and you'll possible find more if you dig deep into the web). The two I know from the top of my head are:

- [Modern UI for WPF](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui)
- [Universal WPF](https://github.com/dotMorten/UniversalWPF)

The first one giving you more UI controls, the second one is focusing on the new Windows 10 controls like `SplitView` and `RelativePanel`.

A good place to get you started layout-wise if you want to create your own controls, is dig into the styles for these existing controls (if you installed the 8.1 and 10 SDKs).

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt\xaml\design
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic

Answer (score 5):

For everyone who is looking for an answer to this problem.
There is a NuGet package to bring the Metro Design to WPF applications:
https://mahapps.com/